# Making x-axis tics from column in data file in Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a data file in the following format.

```
/foo.jsp 1234
/bar.jsp 6653
/foobar.jsp 9986
/bar.jsp 2221
/foo.jsp 5643
```

I want to plot this file in Gnuplot where the tics on the x axis is taken from the first column and the values on the y axis from the second column. To illustrate I would like the chart to look something like this:

```
10000    x           x
5000     x           x          x
0      /foo.jsp /bar.jsp /foobar.jsp
```

Where the x's are the points in the chart.

The best I have managed to do is:

```
plot "datafile.dat" using 2:xticlabel(1) with points
```

However, that command repeats the tics for each value in the first column (i.e. I get two /foo.jsp tics on the x axis). I would like there to be one unique tic for each unique string in the first column.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you should include a column with just the x number, say foo.jsp=1 , bar.jsp=2, etc. and suppose you put this in the first column.

So your datafile would look like:

1 foo.jsp 1234
2 bar.jsp 6653
3 foobar.jsp 9986
2 bar.jsp 2221
1 foo.jsp 5643

Then use:

```
plot "datafile.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) with points
```

Comment: I assume you mean that I should put unique numbers for each unique string in the second column above? That seems to work if I try it here. However, that reuires pre-processing to associate each label with a number. It is doable but it would be best if we could avoid it. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: That would be: plot "datafile.dat" using 2:xtic(1) with points, I checked it and it works, but it looks very similar to your initial solution.

Comment: Furthermore, if you really want 2 points above xlabel "foo.jsp" you will have to put a unique number before "foo.jsp"

Comment: We'll probably go with the solution to pre process the data files and add a unique ID per JSP. Could you edit your answer to include unique IDs for the jsp's with the same name and I'll accept it?

Comment: I updated the solution, each jsp has now its own (unique) id and the resulting plot looks like what you described in your question.