# How to gnuplot 2D numerical data but with xtics showing alphabetical tics instead?

Tags: gnuplot

Say we got this data 'file.dat':

```
0.1 2
0.5 1
0.7 3
1.3 23
1.4 20
2.7 2
2.3 6
5.3 50
5.2 50
```

I wish to plot this as follows:

- 2D plot (lines is fine), like normal.
- **Except:** xtics label shows the following names instead: "small", "medium", "big" marked exactly at x values 0, 3 and 5, respectively.

**Q:** How to achieve this?

Permissible actions:

- I can modify existing or create new 'file.dat' files.
- I can modify gnuplot commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set xtics ("small" 0, "medium" 3, "big" 5)
plot 'file.dat' with lines lw 2 lc rgb "black"
```

should work.

For more information type `help xtics`:

> The explicit (""  , ...) form allows arbitrary tic 
>   positions or non-numeric tic labels.  In this form, the tics do not 
>   need to be listed in numerical order.  Each tic has a  position,
>   optionally with a label.  Note that the label is  a string enclosed by
>   quotes.  It may be a constant string, such as  "hello", may contain
>   formatting information for converting the  position into its label,
>   such as "%3f clients", or may be empty, "".  See `set format` for more
>   information.  If no string is given, the  default label (numerical) is
>   used.
>
> An explicit tic mark has a third parameter, the level.  The default
>   is level 0, a major tic.  Level 1 generates a minor tic.  Labels are
>   never printed for minor tics.  Major and minor tics may be 
>   auto-generated by the program or specified explicitly by the user. 
>   Tics with level 2 and higher must be explicitly specified by the user,
>   and  take priority over auto-generated tics.  The size of tics marks
>   at each  level is controlled by the command `set tics scale`.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>    set xtics ("low" 0, "medium" 50, "high" 100)
>    set xtics (1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024)
>    set ytics ("bottom" 0, "" 10, "top" 20)
>    set ytics ("bottom" 0, "" 10 1, "top" 20)
> ```

Comment: Nice :) - extra question: is it possible to encode the "small", "medium", "big" in the data file 'file.dat' itself?

Comment: I think this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805930/making-x-axis-tics-from-column-in-data-file-in-gnuplot) is that you're looking for